# Apple watch push controller without animation is this possible?

Tags: apple-watch

I wanna know if it is possible that apple watch can push a controller without animation. And also if controller can do pop without animation.

Because I saw the default calendar APP. When I leave calendar APP in calendar main screen, and then click the event(complications) on the clock face. It can go to the detail screen automatically without animation.So how can I do like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this if you don't mind reloading RootPageControllers:

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["the-next-controller"], contexts: nil, orientation: .horizontal, pageIndex: 0)
```

This will happen with no animation.